# MySQL need to add random dates in a colum between 20 years and 90 years

Tags: mysql, date, random

To be used as random birthdays. Need **only** the date to be generated.
I used this but is not working.

```
UPDATE table SET column=FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND((RAND() * (2838240000 - 630720000) + 630720000)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gordon Linoff has the right approach.

Assuming "between 20 and 90 years" means back from today's current date, that would be the same as from 90 years before today's date, plus a random number of days (between 0 and 70*365)

I'd use `DATE(NOW())` to return the current date, then subtract 90 years, and then add in a random number of days. I'd use this expression (assign the return from this to the column in an UPDATE statement). It's just easier for me to decipher.

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET col = DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -90 YEAR + INTERVAL RAND()*70*365.25 DAY
```

---

If "between 20 and 90 years" specifies some particular range of date values, then use an expression that returns the "start" of that range as a DATE value, and add a random interval (in days) that is the within the range of 0 and 70 years.

Answer (score 2):

Your random values are exceeding the max of a signed unix timestamp, of 2^31:

```
2^31 =  2,147,483,648

MariaDB [test]> select from_unixtime(2147483648), from_unixtime(2147483647);
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(2147483648) | from_unixtime(2147483647) |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| NULL                      | 2038-01-18 21:14:07       |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In other words, you're suffering from the Y2038k problem.

e.g.

```
MariaDB [test]> select ROUND((RAND() * (2838240000 - 630720000) + 630720000));
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ROUND((RAND() * (2838240000 - 630720000) + 630720000)) |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                             2234566951 |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select from_unixtime(2234566951);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(2234566951) |
+---------------------------+
| NULL                      |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1. For good explanation of the 32-bit signed integer value issue/limitation of the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function. The MySQL `DATE` datatype has a much larger range of values than the `TIMESTAMP` type.